# Cover Exception statements in java unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, testing, testng

How to write unit test for this block of code

```
   if (!isVisible()) {
       throw new IllegalStateException("Not in xyz page");
   }
   return this.isAttached(DOT_ID);
```

If `isVisible()` is mocked to return `false` then how to write the unit test for the exception statement

Answer (score 6):

With testng, you can annotate your test method like this :

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = IllegalStateException.class, 
      expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = "...")
public void your_test() {
  [...]
}
```